# Why don't my variables reset on the second click event in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I'm simply trying to add a class to a parent of the item I clicked and remove it on the next click (a toggle):

```js
jQuery('.bg').on('click', function(event) {
  let current_target = jQuery(event.currentTarget);
  let current_tooltip = current_target.parents('.tooltip');

  if (!current_target.hasClass('open')) {
    current_tooltip.addClass('open');
  } else {
    current_tooltip.removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.bg {
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```

Problem is, with my code, the `current_target` and `current_tooltip` or rather, everything remains in the **state it was when it was first clicked, as in, the data does not reset on my next click.**

What am I missing?

Comment: Change this `if (!current_target.hasClass('open')) { ... }` to this `if (!current_tooltip.hasClass('open')) { ... }`.

Comment: @N'Bayramberdiyev Thanks, but it still doesn't answer my question as to why the data isn't unique for each event. Or rather - is that the problem?

Comment: On the first click it works, because current_target does not have the class `open`. On the second click it fails, because current_target still doesn't have the class `open`, since the class has been added to current_tooltip, not current_target.

Answer (score 0):

This should simplify it a bit:

```
jQuery('.bg').on('click', function(event) {
  jQuery(event.currentTarget).parents('.tooltip').toggleClass('open'); 
});
```

The toggleClass function adds or removes a class.

Comment: Does not answer why the state remains the same, tho.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.bg' , function() {    
     let current_tooltip = current_target.parents('.tooltip');

     if (!current_target.hasClass('open')) {
        current_tooltip.addClass('open');
     } else {
        current_tooltip.removeClass('open');
     }
  });
```

you can to use in this way, to use DOCUMENT, this will work at any click.

Answer (score 0):

Yo had set th open-class to tooltip and checked for target-class.

```js
jQuery('.bg').on('click', function(event) {
  let current_target = jQuery(event.currentTarget);
  let current_tooltip = current_target.parents('.tooltip');

  //if (!current_target.hasClass('open')) {
  if (!current_tooltip.hasClass('open')) {
    current_tooltip.addClass('open');
  } else {
    current_tooltip.removeClass('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.bg {
    background-color: black;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tooltip">
  <div class="bg"></div>
</div>
```